# What is this GHC feature called? `forall` in type definitions

Tags: haskell, ghc, forall

I learned that you can redefine `ContT` from [transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Cont.html#t:ContT) such that the `r` type parameter is made *implicit* (and may be specified explicitly using `TypeApplications`), viz.:

```hs
-- | Same as `ContT` but with the `r` made implicit
type ContT ::
  forall (r :: Type).
  (Type -> Type) ->
  Type ->
  Type
data ContT m a where
  ContT ::
    forall r m a.
    {runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r} ->
    ContT @r m a

type ContVoid :: (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
type ContVoid = ContT @()
```

I hadn't realized this was possible in GHC. What is the larger feature called to refer to this way of defining a family of types with *implicit* type parameters, that is specified using `forall` in type definition (referring, in the example above, to the outer `forall` - rather than the inner `forall` which simply unifies the `r`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody uses this (invisible dependent quantification) for this purpose (where the dependency is not used) but it is the same as giving a `Type -> ..` parameter, implicitly.

```
type EITHER :: forall (a :: Type) (b :: Type). Type
data EITHER where
 LEFT  :: a -> EITHER @a @b
 RIGHT :: b -> EITHER @a @b

eITHER :: (a -> res) -> (b -> res) -> (EITHER @a @b -> res)
eITHER left right = \case
 LEFT  a -> left  a
 RIGHT b -> right b
```

You can also use "visible dependent quantification" where `forall->` is the visible counterpart to `forall.`, so `forall (a :: Type) -> ..` is properly like `Type -> ..` where *a* does not appear in *..*:

```
type EITHER :: forall (a :: Type) -> forall (b :: Type) -> Type
data EITHER a b where
 LEFT  :: a -> EITHER a b
 RIGHT :: b -> EITHER a b

eITHER :: (a -> res) -> (b -> res) -> (EITHER a b -> res)
eITHER left right = \case
 LEFT  a -> left  a
 RIGHT b -> right b
```

Comment: Can you point to the GHC user guide where these are explained?

Comment: [This](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/poly_kinds.html?highlight=dependent%20quantification#implicit-quantification-in-type-synonyms-and-type-family-instances) explains {in,}visible arguments, but this is ultimately regular kind polymorphism where the quantification is "not used". This is unusual, normally the quantifiee *k* appears in the rest of the kind `Proxy :: forall (k :: Type). k -> Type`. If it doesn't, it is like in type theory where a function arrow `A -> B` is a special case of a dependent function `pi (a :: A) -> B` if *a* does not appear in *B*

Comment: I don't know of any use of this. Let me know if you find any. I remember playing around with this, the invisible case `forall (a :: Type). Type` was pretty unsuable and I think `forall (a :: Type) -> Type` was not the same as `Type -> Type` but it's been a while

Comment: @Iceland_jack [Here](https://twitter.com/sridca/status/1488589875339317256) is a real-world use; backwards compatibility, basically.